# Make an Add a toLocaleDateString year with a number in javascript

Tags: javascript, calendar

I want to override the coptic year by adding 4525 in order to get `6264` **The Egyptain Year when this Ask Posted**

```js
new Date().toLocaleDateString('ar-u-nu-arab', { calendar:'coptic', year: "numeric"}).replace('ERA1','') + 4525
```

How can I add the code above to a number?

Comment: You haven't asked a question, but I suspect you are struggling with the fact that you are appending a number to a string. Do your conversion last.

Comment: yes I do, I add the question

Comment: @EyadFarah Look at this page. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_type_conversion.asp

Comment: Take a look at what `toLocaleDateString()` returns; what would you expect the result to be when adding a string and a number?

Comment: its add a string like `1739 ERA1` and I want only 139 to be added

Comment: What's your expected result? You are concatenating a string and and a number, which yields a string.